# Cast a ptr::null() to a Windows handle

Tags: winapi, rust, user32

I'm trying to use the winapi crate to create a GUI for my [VST plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology). Functions like `user32::SetMenu` need some handles, some of which can be `NULL`.

The following method is called when the plugin is loaded:

```
fn open(&mut self, window: *mut c_void) {
    unsafe {
        let menu = user32::CreateMenu();
        let sub_menu = user32::CreateMenu();
        let hwnd: HWND = window as HWND;
        user32::SetMenu(hwnd, menu);
        let mut data = OsString::from("heee");
        let raw = &mut data as *mut _ as LPWSTR;
        let mut menu_item = MENUITEMINFOW {
            cbSize: 0,
            fMask: 0o0000_0020 | 0o0000_0040,
            fType: 0,
            fState: 0,
            wID: MENUITEM_ID,
            hSubMenu: sub_menu,
            hbmpChecked: ptr::null() as HBITMAP,
            hbmpUnchecked: ptr::null() as HBITMAP,
            dwItemData: 0,
            dwTypeData: raw,
            cch: 0,
            hbmpItem: ptr::null() as *mut _,
        };
        menu_item.cbSize = mem::size_of_val(&menu_item) as u32;
        user32::InsertMenuItemW(menu, MENUITEM_ID, 0, &menu_item);
    }

    self.open = true;
}
```

However, I can't pass `NULL` for the handles:

```
hbmpChecked: ptr::null() as HBITMAP,
```

I get the error message

```
hbmpChecked: ptr::null() as HBITMAP,
             ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

I can't find a solution in the docs of winapi/user32.

Comment: Using ptr::null_mut() was the solution. The casts could be removed, too. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is how `HBITMAP` is defined in winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.2.8/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/windef/type.HBITMAP.html):

```
type HBITMAP = *mut HBITMAP__;
```

This makes `HBITMAP` a mutable raw pointer. [`ptr::null()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.null.html) returns a const raw pointer. You should use [`ptr::null_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.null_mut.html) instead, as it returns a mutable raw pointer, so the compiler will be able to infer the correct type.